# Errores al usar librerias estaticas en QT

Tags: c++, c, qt

Hola estoy un poco desesperado con esto si alguien ha trabajado con este ide que porfavor me especifique porque no puedo crear una version estatica? 
Los errores son:

> Makefile:66: recipe for target 'sub-tools-make_first' failed
>   mingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-tools-make_first] Error 2 mingw32-make[1]:
>   Target 'first' not remade because of errors. makefile:220: recipe for
>   target 'module-qtdeclarative-make_first' failed mingw32-make: ***
>   [module-qtdeclarative-make_first] Error 2 mingw32-make: Target 'first'
>   not remade because of errors.

El tutorial que tome y que se supone que es el correcto y que deberia funcionar:
http://dimitris.apeiro.gr/2015/06/24...-by-compiling/

una captura sobre el error que no logro solucionar :c
https://i.imgsafe.org/e20f9bd6ee.png

Comment: El enlace que has puesto pone: "The page you are looking for cannot be found."

Comment: ¿Es un proyecto `C` o `C++`? ¿qué configuración de proyecto tienes? ¿podrías compartir el contenido de tu `makefile`? ¿estás utilizando alguna librería externa? ¿sale algún error previo al que has copiado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno primero que nada Qt por defecto detecta el Qmake que se tiene instalado en el sistema, en mi caso me aparece de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para trabajar con las librerias estaticas tambien se tiene que observar como es que se esta creando el proyecto, por ejemplo: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Seleccionamos que tipo de librería vamos a utilizar pero para evitar mas problemas te recomiendo que vayas a las siguientes ligas de Stackoverflow donde ya se hablo sobre este problema.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361229/using-a-static-library-in-qt-creator
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965147/how-to-use-static-library-in-qt-5-2
- Extra: http://dimitris.apeiro.gr/2015/06/24/build-a-static-qt5-for-windows-by-compiling/